# Guardar animation frame by frame

Tags: android, animación, sharedpreferences

tengo una animación frame by frame en xml. Mi duda es si es posible guardarla en shared preferences y como hacerlo.

Gracias.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="true">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen1" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen2" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen3" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen4" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen5" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen6" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen7" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen8" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen9" android:duration="85"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/imagen10" android:duration="85"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: Zekirak, es posible guardar los datos de tu animación pero no sería algo correcto, simplemente agregala dentro del folder /anim y de ahí puedes accederla, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario guardar tu animación en Shared preferences, simplemente agrega el archivo dentro del folder `/anim` (si no existe puedes crearlo), esto dentro del directorio de recursos `/res`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma puedes usar tu animación, accediendola desde el folder `/res/anim`:

```
Animation myAnimacion = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.my_animacion);
```